# Averageifs showing divide by 0 error with one extra criteria. However there are multiple acceptable criteria

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have built a hub that tracks training for individuals at our work. I am trying to eliminate the reviews of team members who no longer work from the total team average for us without having to manually delete them all.

I am using AVERAGEIFS:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Clean Training Data'!$F$2:$F,'Clean Training Data'!$D$2:$D,$D$65,'Clean Training Data'!$K$2:$K,TRUE,'Clean Training Data'!$L$2:$L,TRUE,'Clean Training Data'!$M$2:$M,TRUE)
```

The above is returning a DIV/0! error.

While the one below with one less criteria returns the appropriate value.

```
=iferror(Averageifs('Clean Training Data'!$F$2:$F,'Clean Training Data'!$D$2:$D,$D65,'Clean Training Data'!$K$2:$K,TRUE,'Clean Training Data'!$L$2:$L,TRUE),"-")
```

In the first formula I have removed the iferror wrap in an effort to find what the error is.

All of these columns reference a TRUE / FALSE value.

Here is the link to the sheet :
[Training Hub](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nfWiGFaMswBi2fvOCoyICmZFF2azEXkTrI6RZN0O_Nk/edit#gid=1876903380)

Comment: The `M` column is displayed as TRUE/FALSE, while the other columns are displayed as WAAR/ONWAAR. So I guess the `M` column is not interpreted as a boolean (while the others are), but just as text "TRUE".

Comment: Wow. Very simple mistake. Thank you! I guess you get numb to the functions after a bit, I appreciate the extra set of eyes.